# Pandas Rolling On DateTime Multi Index Frame

Tags: python, pandas

There are similar questions, but my `datetime` objects are very spatial and not ordered e.g. they are random timestamps in time. Basically what I need is to use `rolling()` but roll it over the 2nd index while remembering the group (1st index).

There is a very similar GitHub issue that you might also want to contribute to:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15584

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'id': ['A','A','A','B'],
    'time': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-04 08:13:51.181','2018-01-04 08:13:55.181','2018-01-04 09:13:51.181', '2018-01-04 08:13:51.183']),
    'colA': [4,3,2,1],
    '30min_rolling_output': [4,7,2,1],
    '1day_rolling_output': [4,7,9,1]
}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data).set_index(['id', 'time'])
```

The desired output is assuming the `30m` and `1h` arguments.

Visualising:

```
                            colA  30min_rolling_output  1day_rolling_output
id date                                                          
A  2018-01-04 08:13:51.181     4                     4                    4
   2018-01-04 08:13:55.181     3                     7                    7
   2018-01-04 09:13:51.181     2                     2                    9
B  2018-01-04 08:13:51.183     1                     1                    1
```

Comment: As of today, rolling over a specific `DateTime` level of a `MultiIndex` is still not supported. The relevant open issue may be found here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34642

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `id` from the index, leaving you with a `DatetimeIndex` that you can then roll.

```
test_df['30min'] = test_df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('id').colA.rolling('30min').sum()
test_df['1day'] = test_df.reset_index(level=0).groupby('id').colA.rolling('1d').sum()
```

## Output

```
                            colA  30min  1day
id time                                      
A  2018-01-04 08:13:51.181     4    4.0   4.0
   2018-01-04 08:13:55.181     3    7.0   7.0
   2018-01-04 09:13:51.181     2    2.0   9.0
B  2018-01-04 08:13:51.183     1    1.0   1.0
```